# good merkle hash tree python implementation?

Tags: python

Is there any good python implementation of merkle hash tree ? I googled and couldn't find any good one. Can any one suggest a good library for merkle hash tree ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this implementation](http://svn.tribler.org/abc/branches/mainbranch/Tribler/Core/Merkle/merkle.py) in Python.

Also on Github [here](https://github.com/sangeeths/merkle-tree/blob/master/mt.py) there seems to be a basic implementation, worth giving it a try.

Comment: I removed the blank repo, but the other link contains a Python implementation.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently a new one [here](https://github.com/FoteinosMerg/pymerkle), generating also [consistency-proofs](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/log-proofs-work) except for the standard (audit).

I find it highly configurable (you can select hash and encoding types) and very convenient (you can encrypt strings, bytes and whole files very simply). I'm not sure about the tree structure (it seems a bit different from other implementations) but definitely worth giving a try.