# Is it possible to generate a binary / Merkle tree with ShellScript?

Tags: shell, hash, binary-tree

I have a list of generate MD5 hash values and that are URL's of documents ( generated by WGET) on ShellScript on bash. (mac) I was just wondering is there anyway my shellscript can generate a merkle tree or if thats possible as I concatenate the hashes?

Comment: Question: why bash? Why not Python, or at least Perl? Doing anything remotely complicated in bash is a pain.

Comment: I just wanted to know it its possible/ if it could be done and I have already statrted in bash

Comment: Bash doesn't really support arithmetic. Bash does have some support arrays, but the syntax is obtuse. If it were me, I would rewrite in Python and then it's just a case of using [the right library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641479/good-merkle-hash-tree-python-implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible... [Bash is Turing complete](https://www.quora.com/Is-Bash-Turing-complete), so anything is possible given enough CPU time, memory and - in this case especially - programming effort.

You *may* have to convert back and forth to string values though, e.g. first retrieve the hash as hexadecimals, remove the surrounding structures, concatenate, then hash again. If possible, keep the intermediate hashes as binary values.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a punishment that would be inflicted on programmers in Greek mythology - a Sisyphean task. But +1 because it is nonetheless true.